# Subset of the value of each field in a MATLAB structure

Tags: matlab

say have a structure called data with fields called data1 data2, data3, data4 that have many items in them. But i want to crate a variable newdata which has the same fields but only the first 100 items of each field in it. does anyone know a quick way to do this without a loop or a brute force method?

```
                           data1: [3744x1 double]
                           data2: [3744x1 double]
                           data3: [3744x1 double]
                           data4: [3744x1 double]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [STRUCTFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/structfun.html)

```
newdata = structfun(@(x)x(1:100),data,'uniformOutput',false);
```

Example:

```
>> data = struct('a',1:10,'b',1:10);
>> newdata = structfun(@(x)x(1:3),data,'uniformOutput',false)
newdata = 
    a: [1 2 3]
    b: [1 2 3]
```

Comment: I think you need a `...,'UniformOutput',false)` to make that work.

Comment: @user295944: If you find the answer useful, please consider accepting it.